# Why Integer.parseInt is compiling without try catch?

Tags: java, string, exception, int, parseint

As far as I understand  in java a function which throws an exception should not be compiled without a try and catch or a deceleration in the function above it.
How come then this code is legitimate and dont crush?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer.parseInt("33");
}
```

even though Integer.parseInt() 
Throws: NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(null);` also compiles.

Comment: But my sonarlint tells me to surround `parseInt` with a try &catch.

Answer (score 14):

`NumberFormatException` extends `RuntimeException` which is an unchecked exception that does not need to be caught.

[image]

**Excerpt from the Java Tutorial**

> Because the Java programming language does not require methods to
>   catch or to specify unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException, Error, and
>   their subclasses), programmers may be tempted to write code that
>   throws only unchecked exceptions or to make all their exception
>   subclasses inherit from RuntimeException. Both of these shortcuts
>   allow programmers to write code without bothering with compiler errors
>   and without bothering to specify or to catch any exceptions.
>   **[Full Article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)**

[NumberFormatException Api Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1):

> The *unchecked exception classes* are the runtime exception classes and the error classes.

In other words, every Throwable, that is a `RuntimeException` or a subclass and every Throwable, that is an `Error` or a subclass. They can be catched but catching or `throws` is not mandatory.

> The *checked exception classes* are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are all subclasses of Throwable other than RuntimeException and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses.

In other words, every other `Throwable`. They have to be thrown (`throws`) or catched.

`NumberFormatException`  extends `RuntimeException` and therefore it is one of the *unchecked exception classes* and doesn't have to be catched or thrown be the method.

Answer (score 1):

[`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is a so-called unchecked exception, because it's a subtype of `RuntimeException`.

In java, unchecked exceptions also compile without try-catch

Answer (score 0):

[NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is a `RuntimeException` it is unchecked therefore doesn't need to be catched.

Please check the [documentation] if you don't know what a checked/unchecked `Exception` is[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand in java a function which throws an exception should not be compiled without a try and catch

Right, just change `exception` to `Checked exception`.

Go through following to have a clear idea about these:

[Effective Java Exceptions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html)

[Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatException is a RuntimeException. RuntimeExceptions are unchecked exceptions. What you say is mandatory for checked exception, but not required for unchecked exception.

Couple of link:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

Exception in Java are of two kinds : checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions.

Checked exceptions are the one which need `try-catch` block or declaration.

Unchecked exception do not need that. `NumberFormatException` is an unchecked exception.

Basicaly, unchecked Exception derive from `RuntimeException`, and thus does not need declaration or `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

It is an unchecked exception.The class RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions classes.These exceptions can occur anywhere in your code.So it is upto you to catch that exception and proceed with execution